# Update table with counts from another

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to update a table with the counts of another table. I think I've got the structure of the query right but I keep getting a SQL error:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.sales = p.ProductCount
FROM products c
INNER JOIN
(SELECT p_key, COUNT(*) AS ProductCount 
FROM sales
GROUP BY p_key) p
ON c.link = p.p_key
```

The structure of the two tables:

**Products**
product_name (varchar),
sales (int),
link (char),

**Sales**
email (char),
p_key (char)

I've just shown the key columns. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using the join syntax for `T_SQL`, in `MySQL` do this,

```
UPDATE  products c
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  p_key,
                    COUNT(*) AS ProductCount
            FROM sales
            GROUP BY p_key
        ) p
            ON c.link = p.p_key
SET c.sales = p.ProductCount
```

Comment: [This edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/767026) was completely plagiarized. Please don't mindlessly approve tag wikis without checking for copied content.

Comment: @meagar I approved it since `genbank` has no excerp yet.

Comment: You shouldn't have. It's not OK to plagiarize content. It is, in fact, illegal and against SO's policy.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the right syntax:

```
UPDATE products c
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT p_key, COUNT(*) AS ProductCount 
   FROM sales
   GROUP BY p_key
) p ON c.link = p.p_key
SET c.sales = p.ProductCount
```